# Eleminate a char in String java

Tags: java, string

how can i eleminate the last `,|` in this `String` :

```
String model ="07:40,09:00,10:20,11:40,|09:00,10:20,11:40,|07:40,09:00,10:20,11:40,|10:20,11:40,|";
```

model is variable `String`, and the result should like that :

```
String result="07:40,09:00,10:20,11:40,|09:00,10:20,11:40,|07:40,09:00,10:20,11:40,|10:20,11:40";
```

Comment: Did you look at the String class' javadoc to see the which methods the API offers?

Comment: substring(beginningIndex,endIndex) should work check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's always `,|` and you don't know if it will be present use `replaceFirst`:

```
model = model.replaceFirst(",\\|$", "");
```

P.S. `$` stands for end of String

Comment: It might be worth an explanation that despite we're calling `replaceFirst()`, it matches the last one because of the `$` anchor for end of String in the regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

```
   String model ="07:40,09:00,10:20,11:40,|09:00,10:20,11:40,|07:40,09:00,10:20,11:40,|10:20,11:40,|";
   String result = model.substring(0, model.length() -2);
   System.out.println(result);
```

> javadoc : **substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)** : 
>   Returns a new string that is a substring of this string.

Answer (score 3):

If this always shows up you can cut the end of the string. To do that you can do use this code:

```
result = model.substring(0, path.length() - 2);
```

If it only happens sometimes, you can do this:

```
if (model.substring(path.length - 2, path.length).equals(",|")) {
    result = model.substring(0, path.length() - 2);
} else {
    result = model
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try **StringUtils**:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

// model = "07:40,09:00,10:20,11:40,|09:00,10:20,11:40,|07:40,09:00,10:20,11:40,|10:20,11:40,|"
model = StringUtils.removeEnd(model, ",|");
// Now 
// model = "07:40,09:00,10:20,11:40,|09:00,10:20,11:40,|07:40,09:00,10:20,11:40,|10:20,11:40";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String correctedModel=new StringBuilder(model).deleteCharAt(model.lastIndexOf('|')).toString();
```

Check docs [StringBuilder.deleteChartAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) and [String.lastIndexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#deleteCharAt%28int%29)